# PHP return value from class function not working

Tags: php, return-value, ternary-operator

I am having problem fetching return value returned by a class function in PHP. Does returning values works exactly the way it works in other languages- C, C++, Java or there is something new to it.

This is my Class:

```
class M_UserMaster
{

    private $_db = null;

    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->_db = $db; 
    }


    function checkUserExists($mobNum)
    {
        $userExists = false;

        $sql = "SELECT STATEMENT HERE";

        $stmnt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute();

        $numRows = $stmnt->rowCount();

        echo '<br><br>Num Rows: ' . $numRows . '<br>***';

        $userExists = ($numRows > 0) ? true : false;

        return $userExists;
    }
}
```

The echo statement returns 0. But the function returns nothing.

From another file I am calling it like this:

```
$m_userMaster = new M_UserMaster($db);
$userExists = $m_userMaster->checkUserExists('0000000000');

echo '<br><br>User Exists: ' . $userExists;
```

This is what is printed

> User Exists:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
$x = true;
echo $x;
```

You will get output **1**

But with

```
$x = false;
echo $x;
```

You will get **empty string** as output

You will need to do something like this:

```
echo '<br><br>User Exists: ' . ($userExists ? 'yes' : 'no');
```

Or change return value of your function from `true / false` to `1 / 0`. That will behave similar way, but output will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$userExists = ($numRows > 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

As per your code,if the `$numRows` is greater than `0` then it will return `1` and if the `$numRows` is `0` then it will return `empty` because it become `false`.For clear understand

```
echo true;    // Return 1
echo false;   // Return empty
```

Comment: Goodness me that was funny coz all this time I used functions which returned true or false and not 'true' or 'false'. But they were not in classes- Does that make the difference

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo a literal boolean value. PHP prints such values as empty strings. You want to do something like this, instead:

```
echo '<br><br>User Exists: ' . ($userExists ? 'true' : 'false');
```

This will echo the first part no matter what. It then checks whether `$userExists` is true. If so, it prints `true`; otherwise, it prints `false`.